# Checking if a polynomial is "Not Reducible"

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How I can check if the polynomial $x^4 + 125x^2 + 25x +5$ is **Not irreducible** over $Z$

If its degree would be 2 or 3 than I would have checked if it has zero in $Z$ .
Because let F be a field. If $f(x)$ is a member of $F[x]$ and $deg f(x)= 2 or 3$, then $f(x)$ is reducible over $F$ if and only if $f(x)$ has a zero in $F$. 
But here degree is 4.

*If a polynomial is not irreducible over Z than it is reducible over Z is that so.?*

How should I check in $x^4 + 125x^2 + 25x +5$ if its Not Reducible?

Comment: Hint: use Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Thanks . Yeah in Ist one I can use. But In 2nd one?

Comment: Please do not add questions to an existing problem. Instead ask a new one.

Comment: Sure.....!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [Eisenstein's criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

$$5 \mid 5,\  5\mid25, \ 5\mid 125,\ 5\not \mid 1,\ 5^2 \not \mid 5$$

Therefore, the given polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ and hence over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for being Helpfull